# Was bedeutet "chicks/checks geben" in der Jugendprache?

Tags: meaning, teen-slang

Neulich haben sich meine präpubertären Kinder wieder einmal heftig gestritten und wie immer endete das in Tränen. Auf meine Frage, was denn nun der Grund für diesen Streit war, antwortete mein Sohn (der Ältere von beiden):

> Sie hat mir die ganze Zeit *chicks* gegeben, da musste ich doch was machen.

"Aha, was sind den *chicks*?", wollte ich wissen, aber wie erwartet kam nur ein Achselzucken und ich habe immer noch keine Ahnung, was "chicks" oder eventuell auch "checks geben" in diesem Zusammenhang bedeuten könnte. Die herkömmliche Slang-Bedeutung für [Mädchen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Chick) scheidet vermutlich aus.

Hat das schon jemand gehört? Was könnte mit dem Begriff gemeint sein?

Comment: _Checks_ wie in _Bodycheck_ vielleicht?

Comment: @Crissov: kann sein, er hat es zwar wie *chicks* ausgesprochen, aber im Kontext könnte das gut passen... Antwort?

Comment: Falls Crissov recht hat (was mir plausibel vorkommt), ist das eine moderne Variante von *... schubst mich dauernd*.

Comment: @Crissov: ich habe deinen Kommentar mal als Edit zur Frage aufgenommen, damit deine Antwort passt.

Comment: Also *chicks geben* würde mich wundern, weil *chick* (zumindest noch bis vor kurzem...) In-Wort für "Mädchen" ist. Nach dem Motto *hast du die Chicks da drüben mal ausgechecked?*

Comment: Immer auf die Chicks und Balances achten!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Möglicherweise handelt es sich bei *chick/tschick* lediglich um ein falsch verstandenes bzw. wiedergegebenes englisches Wort, nämlich *check* wie es bereits im Anglizismus *Bodycheck* (u.a. Sportjargon für ‚Rempler‘) vorkommt.

Bei Schlägen u.ä. würde man hochsprachlich als Verb vielleicht *austeilen* erwarten, aber in der Umgangssprache mit seinem beschränktem Begleitvokabular kann *geben* diese Funktion problemlos übernehmen. (Noch reduzierter wäre *machen* oder *tun*.)

Eine völlig andere Herkunft und ggf. Bedeutung kann ich natürlich nicht ausschließen.

Comment: Schließlich konnten sie mir erklären, was das ist: grob anschubsen, bzw. den anderen in den Nacken hauen.... ("das machen doch alle")  also passt wohl *checks*.

Answer (score 4):

Ich glaube ich habe es! Im britischen Slang heißt

> to give cheek

Respektlosigkeit bekunden. So jemand wird auch als **cheeky** beschrieben.

[urban Dictionary - give cheek](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheek)

Ungleich widerlicher ist die Wendung [hier](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Give%20up%20dem%20cheeks).

Der erste Begriff hat es durch [Skins](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skins_(UK_TV_series)#Reception) zu einer gewissen Bekanntheit gebracht. Diese Serie möchte, laut Wikipedia, extreme Seiten der Pubertät betonen, verbreitet also gewiss noch viel fragwürdiges Englisch.